# Windows 10 WiFi Adapters

Tags: wifi, windows, windows-iot

I have two Raspberry Pis

- **RP B+** running Raspbian
- **RP 2** running Windows 10 IoT Core

I have a **Vilros USB WiFi adapter** (details [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00T53135O/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=B00T53135O&linkCode=as2&tag=liqui-21)) that works in **Raspbian** but not in **Windows 10 IoT Core**.

In **Raspbian** the adpater has a blue light when connected. I do not see this in **Win 10 IoT Core**.

Has anyone used any success with a Vilros Adapter, or any other WiFi adapters (*other* than the recommended [official Pi Wifi Adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B012CTHSVK/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=B012CTHSVK&linkCode=as2&tag=liqui-21)) on **Windows 10 IoT Core**?

---

**UPDATE 29/02/2016**

With the release of Raspberry Pi 3 (with integrated WiFi) this conversation may well become moot.

Comment: Windows systems genrally need many drivers installed specially for the hardware (unlike Linux which has loads of generic and specific drivers). The ioT version for the Pi may however may include some of the drivers that may be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/12/03/whats-new-for-windows-10-iot-this-fall/

> Another common request we have seen is to support additional Wi-Fi
>   dongles. In this release, we not only support the official Raspberry
>   Pi Wi-Fi dongle, but also two Realtek Wi-Fi chipsets (RTL8188EU &
>   RTL8192EU). These chipsets are included in dongles like the TP-LINK
>   TL_WN725N, along with several other dongles. This makes connecting
>   your Windows 10 IoT Core device to the net much easier.

For example;

- [Realtek RTL8188EU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter 150Mbps](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00XL5TPDE/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=B00XL5TPDE&linkCode=as2&tag=liqui-21)
- [TP-LINK TL-WN725N 150Mbps Wireless-N Nano USB Adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B008IFXQFU/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=B008IFXQFU&linkCode=as2&tag=liqui-21)

Answer (score 7):

The official RPF Dongle uses the Broadcom BCM43143 Chipset.

The official dongle will work.  If you don't have the official dongle but your dongle is based on the Broadcom BCM43143 chipset it might work.  If it is based on anything else it will not work.

Comment: OK to confirm your vocab, BCM43143 _might_ work and all others definitely _won't_ work?

Comment: @MarkCooper That's the situation to the best of my knowledge.  With the proviso that if you use the official dongle it will work.  I'll  make that clearer in the answer.

Comment: I've brought an official pi wifi and now the HDMI has stopped working :-(

Comment: @MarkCooper Hopefully one has nothing to do with the other!

Comment: Nope the HDMI issue was solved by adding an additional line to config.txt - solved with this information: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=105&t=113759 And WiFI is now working perfectly with the RaPi adapter.

Comment: @zespri When did you download Windows 10 IoT?  WIFI support is recent.  When did you buy the dongle?

Comment: What is "The official RPF Dongle"? Can you post a link where can I buy one?

Comment: The questioner posted a link.

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm that as of build 10586, the TP-LINK TL-WN725N is now working!

Here is the link: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008IFXQFU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008IFXQFU)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Just picked it up and it's working great!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the official Microsoft list of supported WiFi dongles.

http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm#WiFi-Dongles

(also lists other supportd devices)

Answer (score 0):

In fact the official Microsoft list is not clear enough.
Playing with RPi2 and 10.0.10586, I tried several dongles that should be working but that didn't.

I have an "official" WiPi dongle for my old RPi B+ that dont work.

I tried a Realtek 8191SU WLAN adapter that didn't work.
The official list says 8191 is recognized but don't tell much about suffix letters.

I tried a Realtek 8192CU WLAN Adapter. Yet, 8192 is good for the list but not for the Win 10 IoT.

When we buy a dongle, we don't really know the exact flavor of the chipset that is used. Unfortunately, the chipset variant seems to be important. So buying a Wifi dongle looks like playing lottery.
Perhaps the right answer will come from dongle makers like EDIMAX that releases drivers for its dongles on RPi2 Win10 IoT!